# Track Facebook user visiting website

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have a link placed in facebook, and I would like to track the user if they clicked the link and visited the site? Is this possible.

I don't want the user to have to log into the site or anything:

Example:

1. User clicks link
2. User redirected to my site.
3. I know who user is on facebook.

Thanks

If anyone knows of a better way to accomplish this without the user having to log into the site, please let me know

Comment: Evil, but possible to at least know if they're currently logged in: https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information

Answer (score 7):

No, Facebook does not pass the user's information in this way. It'd be a significant privacy issue.

Answer (score 0):

Write a facebook app that stores all of this in a database. 
then, require the user to authenticate to your site using said app.

refs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

Answer (score 0):

if you have an app, and the link is inside your app.  THEN, you can get user information for those who accept your app.

However, if you mean just posting a link on your personal wall, then, the link won't give you any information at all.  Even _SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]  will not give you the user info.